# Why is the statement "columns of matrix must be linear dependent when row > column" true?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces

How does the linear dependence related to the number of rows and columns of matrix?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is the other way around. If there are more columns that rows, say $m$ and $n$ with $m>n$ then the columns of the matrix $v_{1},...,v_{m}\in\mathbb{R}^{n}$ must be linearly dependent.

This is called the exchange lemma, that if $v_{1},...,v_{m}\in V$ and the dimension of $V$ is less than $m$ then $v_{1},...,v_{m}$ is linearly dependent.

The proof sketch is that we assume $v_{1},...,v_{m}$ is linearly independent and so we can take $v_{1},...,v_{n}$ as a basis where $n<m$ is the dimension of the space. Then $v_{n+1}$ can be expressed as a linear combination of $v_{1},...,v_{n}$ which is a contradiction.

Comment: Another way to think about it is that if the matrix represented some system of linear equations $Ax=b$ then the number of columns is the number of unknowns, and the number of rows is the number of constraints. If #columns>#rows, then there are more unknowns than constraints, so there will be degrees of freedom left in the solution $x$.

Answer (score 1):

The statement, as you wrote it, is false. For example, the matrix $$\begin{bmatrix} 1\\ 2\end{bmatrix}$$ has linearly independent columns, even though it has more rows than columns.